# Concentric Tube Capacitive Fluid Level Sensor Troubles

Tags: sensor, capacitance

I'm a mechanical engineering student working on my senior design project. We are trying to measure a fluid level inside a tank using a capacitive sensor. Originally, the team had designed a parallel plate capacitive sensor. We were able to see a change in fluid level using a multimeter with this type of setup. We did our testing with water. The fluid that we will be measuring is actually oil, which has a dielectric constant 97% lower than water, making the parallel plate design ineffective because of a lack of surface area. Additionally, we can't increase the size of the plates due to packaging constraints. We ended up deciding to go forward with a concentric tube capacitive sensor design which would allow us to maximize the surface area of the sensing elements. This is where the troubles began.

I have assembled a simple prototype using aluminum tubing, I have made sure to remove any factory coating as well as ensuring the two tubes were electrically isolated. Here's where the fun begins. My prototype responds to touch, but when immersed in water, there is no change in capacitance. Only when I remove the sensor do I see a capacitance change on my meter. I have also tried switching the polarity to no avail.

Please pardon my lack of knowledge regarding this subject. I have done lots of internet searching as well as asking my undergraduate research prof about what I could possibly be doing wrong. Granted, I might not be asking the right questions which could be part of my search problem.

Comment: Why are you testing with water when oil will be what you need to measure? Water can be conductive and that can affect your measurement, especially with an unsophisticated measuring instrument. How about a dimensioned drawing and your calculations of the capacitance (with oil) for empty and full conditions? Also a description of the measuring instrument and the connections to it (type of wire, length).

Comment: You don't talk about the probe dimensions, but from building sensors like this in the past, you need to ensure there is ventilation at the top, and consider the impact of capillary action. 

If the sensor is responding to touch of the outer tube, you might also have a wiring / meter issue, because the inner wire should be eletrically shielded, so the capacitance should not change.  

Photos or diagrams with dimensions might help spot the issue.

You also need to consider stray capacitance on the leads, where use of coax is strongly recommended.